# iPhone ignoring CSS Stylesheet

Tags: iphone, css

I'm working on my very first (very lame) website, so apologies for the n00b question.

In Chrome/FF/Safari, my site renders the CSS fine. But on my iPhone or iPad (Chrome or Safari), my site renders as if there were no CSS styles at all. What's the cause?

Link to [site](http://www.tvsonsale.co.uk)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

you are referencing localhost for your stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8888/kirbydev/assets/styles/styles.css" />
```

needs to be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tvsonsale.co.uk/kirbydev/assets/styles/styles.css" />
```

or relative path so it works on local dev and production:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/kirbydev/assets/styles/styles.css" />
```